# FN key permanently activated although deactivated in the BIOS

Tags: shortcut-keys, function-keys

My <kbd>Fn</kbd> key is permanently activated/pressed, although it is deactivated in the BIOS. In Ubuntu pressing the <kbd>FN</kbd>+<kbd>ESC</kbd> keys doesn't do anything. Numlock is deactivated in the BIOS, so it can't interfere with the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key.

I only want the FN functions upon pressing the FN key, hence any idea how to achieve this?

My machine is a Dell 9560 - latest UK version.

Ubuntu 16.04, latest standard updates, Kernel 4.8.0.51-generic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have managed to solve the problem. In Dell's boot options under 'POST Behaviour' --> 'Fn Lock Option' keep the check mark for 'Fn Lock' and below select 'Lock Mode Enable/Secondary'.

It seems wrong to select this because 'Lock Mode Enable/Secondary' is defined as:

> The <kbd>F1</kbd>-<kbd>F12</kbd> keys control the secondary functions. <kbd>Fn</kbd> is required to
>   access the standard functions.

However, exactly the opposite is the case when selecting this option. <kbd>F1</kbd>-<kbd>F12</kbd> work as function keys and only when <kbd>Fn</kbd> is pressed the secondary functions, e.g. volume down/up, brightness down/up, are triggered.

I found this solution on [http://vetruvet.blogspot.de](http://vetruvet.blogspot.de/2017/02/linux-on-xps-15-95509560-with-tb16-dock.html).

Comment: I use an apple wired keyboard, and it does not copy that bios setting; There is a linux kernel module that interacts with the settings of that keyboard:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Apple_Keyboard#hid_apple_module_options

It is handy to set those defaults in the kernel commandline in grub, so your keyboard works fine immediately after booting.